# How to get method of form using javascript or jquery when we submit a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, httpwebrequest

How to get method of form using javascript or jquery when we submit a form at client ?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery if there is a form with id 'post-form', $('#post-form')[0].method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#yourformid").attr('method')
```